# formula for computing inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am pretty sure I once heard of a formula of computing the inverse of a matrix $I-A$ based on the inverse of $A$, but I can't remember the name of the formula. Is there a shortcut for computing the inverse of $I-A$?

Comment: $\sum_nA^n$: would this be a shortcut? Of course, $I-A$ does not need to be invertible, e.g., $A=I$.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [matrix inversion lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_formula) (also known as Woodbury formula)?

Answer (score 0):

as Degtyarev commented, it could be the [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).

$ (I - A)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k$

when it is invertible.